# Strange issue with socket.on method

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am facing a strange issue with calling `socket.on` methods from the Javascript client. Consider below code:

```
for(var i=0;i<2;i++) {
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000/');
  socket.emit('getLoad');
  socket.on('cpuUsage',function(data) {
        document.write(data);
  });
 }
```

Here basically I am calling a `cpuUsage` event which is emitted by socket server, but for each iteration I am getting the same value. This is the output:

```
0.03549148310035006
0.03549148310035006
0.03549148310035006
0.03549148310035006
```

**Edit:** Server side code, basically I am using node-usage library to calculate CPU usage:

```
socket.on('getLoad', function (data) {

    usage.lookup(pid, function(err, result) {
        cpuUsage = result.cpu;
        memUsage = result.memory;
        console.log("Cpu Usage1: " + cpuUsage);
        console.log("Cpu Usage2: " + memUsage);
        /*socket.emit('cpuUsage',result.cpu);
        socket.emit('memUsage',result.memory);*/
        socket.emit('cpuUsage',cpuUsage);
        socket.emit('memUsage',memUsage);
    });
});
```

Where as in the server side, I am getting different values for each `emit` and `socket.on`. I am very much feeling strange why this is happening. I tried setting `data = null` after each `socket.on` call, but still it prints the same value. I don't know what phrase to search, so I posted. Can anyone please guide me?

Please note: I am basically Java developer and have a less experience in Javascript side.

Comment: Please show the code for cpu usage calculation.

Comment: @user568109, I added server side code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making the assumption that when you use `.emit()`, a subsequent `.on()` will wait for a reply, but that's not how `socket.io` works.

Your code basically does this:

- it emits two `getLoad` messages directly after each other (which is probably why the returning value is the same);
- it installs two handlers for a returning `cpuUsage` message being sent by the server;

This also means that each time you run your loop, you're installing more and more handlers for the same message.

Now I'm not sure what exactly it is you want. If you want to periodically request the CPU load, use `setInterval` or `setTimeout`. If you want to send a message to the server and want to 'wait' for a response, you may want to use acknowledgement functions (not very well documented, but see [this blog post](http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2011/08/17/node-socket-io-curious.html)).

But you should assume that for each type of message, you should only call `socket.on('MESSAGETYPE', )` once during the runtime of your code.

**EDIT**: here's an example client-side setup for a periodic poll of the data:

```
var socket = io.connect(...);

socket.on('connect', function() {
  // Handle the server response:
  socket.on('cpuUsage', function(data) {
    document.write(data);
  });

  // Start an interval to query the server for the load every 30 seconds:
  setInterval(function() {
    socket.emit('getLoad');
  }, 30 * 1000); // milliseconds
});
```

Comment: Basically I want to periodically request for CPU load say every 30 seconds. I was trying to implement that.

Comment: @PradeepSimha I've added an example on how you could implement that

Answer (score 1):

Use this line instead:

var socket = io.connect('iptoserver', {'force new connection': true});

Replace iptoserver with the actual ip to the server of course, in this case localhost.

Edit.
That is, if you want to create multiple clients.

Else you have to place your initiation of the socket variable before the for loop.

Comment: Great! this also made trick. Let me wait for few more answers :) I am not sure, creating new connection everytime is a good practice :)

Comment: Placing the var socket = io.connect(....); before the for() loop in your client side code wouldn't create new connections each time the loop "loops". So its a matter of what you're trying to achieve really.

Comment: I tried placing outside of for loop, but still same issue persists :(

Comment: Oh, okay. Then I can no longer help, my expertise within node.js isn't nearly as great as I would like to :p

Answer (score 1):

I suspected the call returns average CPU usage at the time of startup, which seems to be the case here. Checking the node-usage documentation page ([average-cpu-usage-vs-current-cpu-usage](https://github.com/arunoda/node-usage#average-cpu-usage-vs-current-cpu-usage)) I found:

> By default CPU Percentage provided is an average from the starting
>   time of the process. It does not correctly reflect the current CPU
>   usage. (this is also a problem with linux ps utility)
>
> But If you call usage.lookup() continuously for a given pid, you can
>   turn on keepHistory flag and you'll get the CPU usage since last time
>   you track the usage. This reflects the current CPU usage.

Also given the example how to use it.

```
var pid = process.pid;
var options = { keepHistory: true }
usage.lookup(pid, options, function(err, result) {

});
```